# Union of flattened OrderedDict values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking for a pythonic way to obtain the union of the `.values` of an OrderedDict, *after* collapsing the lists that compose the values.  I'd like the result to be a 1-d list, ordered according to a custom order.

What I'm working with:

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
order = list('acebd')
d = OrderedDict([(1, ['a', 'e']),
                 (2, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
                ])
```

And desired result:

```
['a', 'c', 'e', 'b'] # ordered according to `order`, where len(order)
                     # may be greater than len(result) here
```

My current implementation

```
def flatten(iterable):
    """Flatten a nested iterable.  Not my code."""
    it = iter(iterable)

    for e in it:
        if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
            for f in flatten(e):
                yield f
        else:
            yield e

print(list(set(flatten(d.values()))))
['a', 'e', 'b', 'c']
```

But unsure of how to map to the sorting, and looking for more elegant or faster solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to flatten, they are just simple lists, just `itertools.chain` them together.
You can use the set as a guard in a list comprehension to get the order you want:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
s = set(it.chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
[o for o in order if o in s]

Out[]:
['a', 'c', 'e', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** My answer assumes that order does not matter.

You can use `itertools.chain` and `set`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> d = OrderedDict([(1, ['a', 'e']),
                 (2, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
                ])
>>> set(chain(*d.values()))
{'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Alternatively, you could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
{'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

If order matters, use `list` and `OrderedDict.fromkeys`:

```
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain(*d.values())))
```